# How can I get my photos to align vertically with another element in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get my photos to be aligned vertically with my other photos. They always appear under the last one I've added in HTML. I have looked around but can't seem to find it.

[image: https://gyazo.com/d6d8a422bd95826622c0e36ea2ba5f78]

[image]

**CSS:**

```
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}
h2 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
nav {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20;
}

.frontIMG {
  height: 30%;
  width: 30%;
  border: black solid medium;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.frontIMGcenter {
  display: block;
  margin: 500px 250px;
  height: 30%;
  width: 30%;
  border: black solid medium;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <link href="mainpage.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
        <title> Barton And Son Builders </title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <nav>
            <a href=./MainPage.html> Home </a>
            &nbsp;
            <a href="./AboutPage.html"> About Us</a>
            &nbsp;
            <a href=./Portfolio.html> Portfolio </a>
        </nav>
        &nbsp;
        <main>
            <section>
                <h1>
                    Barton And Son Builders
                </h1>
                <h2> <em> "Foundation To Finish" </em> </h2>
            </section>

            <figure class= "mainIMG">
            <div id= "#crystalcomplete">
            <img src=  "/C:\Users\Ed\Desktop\Photo-Mainpage\The-Crystal-Restaurant\CrystalComplete.jpg" class= "frontIMG"> 
        </div> 
            <br>
             <figcaption class= "figcapMain"> The Crystal Restaurant <br>
            Public Square, Watertown NY. </figcaption>
        </figure>
        
        <figure class= "mainIMG">
            <img src= "/C:\Users\Ed\Desktop\Photo-Mainpage\Black-River\black-river.jpg" class= "frontIMG">
            <br>
            <figcaption class= "figcapmain"> Metal Roof <br>
            Black River, NY.
        </figcaption>
        </figure>

        <figure class= "mainIMG">
            <img src= "/C:\Users\Ed\Desktop\Photo-Mainpage\Spokes-Deck\Spokes-deck.jpg" class= "frontIMGcenter">
            <br>
            <figcaption>Spokes Pressure Treated Deck <br>
            Public Square, Watertown NY. </figcaption>
        </figure>
            
    </body>
    </main>
    </html>
</DOCTYPE>
```

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE>` has no end tag. Look - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23005510/why-is-the-doctype-tag-not-closed

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a `</div>` in the middle of the first figure. Try taking that out and see what happens.
Generally your code should render them all aligned to the left.
Are you editing your code in an editor or just notepad? A rule of thumb is to keep track of open- and close-tags, they can cause mayhem ;) Best of luck!

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio Code. It does render them to the left, the picture in the middle was my attempt to bring the image to the top next to the first image. Basically I want a row with columns of 3 so the front page would have 3 images in a row with 2 under each, total of 6.

Comment: Hmm, so you want to have  
[[image], [image], [image]]  (LINEBREAK)
[[image], [image], [image]]

Comment: Yes I think I meant horizontal when I said vertical. I tried changing the display to inline-block but it didn't do anything. There isn't an interference with not having enough space because it doesn't change it no matter how small the photos are. I've tried a few things and they haven't worked.

Comment: Is there any need for you to build this yourself? I would actually look at a CSS Framework like Bootstrap or similar to get the function you need. Unless you are trying to learn, and please do tell if you are, I would go with a ready-made solution. No need to reinvent the wheel ;)